# Solving RC circuit ODE without integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

[image]

while studying RC circuit, every college book solved voltage in a RC circuit in the same way of solving this ODE.
$$ε= {\frac{q}{c}} + R{\frac{dq}{dt}}$$
$$q=VC(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})$$
However I thought that $q$ and $\frac{dq}{dt}$ are both related to time, so assuming $q=Be^{-At}+D$ is is possible to solve it. Will it be correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is correct. One could justify this as an educated guess or from the general theory of linear differential equations of one variable. We can first *substitute this solution to the equation*:
$$q(t) = Be^{-At}+D \Rightarrow \frac{dq(t)}{dt}=-ABe^{-At},$$
Then
$$\varepsilon = \frac{1}{C}(Be^{-At}+D) -RABe^{-At}$$
$\varepsilon$ will be a constant only if the sum of the terms in front of the exponent is zero, which gives $1/C = RA$ and $\epsilon = D/C$. We thus obtain 
$$A = \frac{1}{RC},\\
D = \varepsilon C,\\
q(t) = \varepsilon C + Be^{-\frac{t}{RC}}.$$
One now can determine $B$ from the *initial conditions*, i.e. from knowing the charge at time $t=0$:
$$q(0) = ...$$

Comment: As I solved, $v=\frac{B}{C}e^{-At}+\frac{D}{C}-ARBe^{-At}$
and then how I should I go on?

Comment: Amazing calculation!! 
To solve like this way, it was important to find what makes E constant...
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!